# "Cannot activate an already activated outlet" error during navigation to another route

Tags: angular

I have 2 different routes which uses `loginOutlet`outlet:

Password Reset Component

```
export const passwordResetFinishRoute: Route = {
    path: 'reset/finish', children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: PasswordResetFinishComponent,
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Password'
            },
            outlet: 'loginOutlet', pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]

};
```

Login component

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', children: [
        {path: '', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'loginOutlet', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]}
];
```

After password reset operation is completed, I want to display `LoginComponent` using following link:

```
<a class="alert-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">sign in</a>.
```

I receive following error:

```
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
```

How can I load `LoginComponent` inside `loginOutlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the root cause of the problem was missing primary router-outlet when user is not logged in:

```
<div *nfIf="loggedIn()" class="content-wrapper">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I changed main template as follows:

```
<div [ngClass]="loggedInClass()"">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

, added `loggedInClass()` which returns the correct css class when user is logged in.

Then, route configuration started to behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Structural directive from router-outlet

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from your answer?